# 'anchor test' - error: no such subcommand: `build-bpf`

Tags: anchor

I'm having a nightmare just setting up Solana tool chain.

I'm a n00b and haven't done any development on Solana yet.

I'm on Ubuntu 24.04

I'm getting this error that I'm unable to fix when running `'anchor test'`

```
error: no such subcommand: `build-bpf`
```

I can't find anything online that helps, and I've spent hours looking - and this is the latest in a huge pile of issues.

thx

Comment: can you share more about your system config

Comment: Sure - what would you like to know?

Comment: did you try reinstalling it? Setting Solana up on Ubuntu and mac is pretty straight forward. usually this error happens when you system is not able to detect installed solana. can you do `solana config get` in the terminal as well

Comment: straightforward lol, really? I've had to nuke and pave 8 Ubuntu installs so far... Finally got it working now but it required a colossal amount of messing around

Comment: It could detect installed solana

Comment: the Pain for Windows folks is greater than us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rebooted Ubuntu and it fixed it.

Doh

Comment: That's not an answer - it doesn't show how you fixed the problem.

Comment: It is literally how I fixed the problem. WHY it worked no idea, but it is what fixed it.

Comment: There are many issues that could be worked around by restarting the entire OS, buying a new computer, moving house, becoming a different person, etc. An answer to the issue would `no such subcommand: `build-bpf`` would typically involve handling how Rust looks for subcommands and resolving that rather than any of the above.